# Could dagger get the context of injection point?

Tags: cdi, dagger

In cdi doc:
https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/InjectionPoint.html

The example shows how to get context by using InjectionPoint:

```
@Produces 
Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) { 
    return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName() );
}
```

I am currently using Dagger2 in my project and I found no such class as InjectionPoint available. So is there any other options?

Thanks

Comment: Dagger is a compile time dependency injection framework, working on the principle of code generation. There would be no need to maintain and injectionpoint, as all the required dependencies are already statically injected.

Comment: Dagger is not CDI compliant implementation afaik. Hence you shouldn't count on CDI API. It just builds on DI specification (JSR-330).

Comment: If you want CDI implementation, use (for instance) Weld. Dagger is *not* CDI impl, just DI.